# PHP/MySQL update query not working at all

Tags: php, mysql

I'm just a beginner in terms of programming, so I'm just referring all my codes through tutorials. Luckily, I found this online tutorial in youtube where users are allowed to add, update, and delete data in mysql using php. I follow all his instructions, I got it working but then it stopped when I added css on it.

This is not a general issue, I just need some help. If anyone can help me, much appreciated. Thank you so much.

**Maintenance.php**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "rssfeed";

$connect = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
if (!$connect) {
    die("Cannot connect: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

mysqli_select_db($connect, $database);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `maintenance`";
$data = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $update = "UPDATE `maintenance` SET `name`='".$_POST['name']."', `url`='".$_POST['url']."', `description`='".$_POST['desc']."' WHERE `name`='".$_POST['hidden']."'";
    mysqli_query($connect, $update);
}

echo""
. "<table>"
. "<tr>"
. "<th>Name</th>"
. "<th>URL</th>"
. "<th>Description</th>"
. "<th colspan=2>Action</th>"
. "</tr>";

while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
    echo""
    . "<form action=maintenance.php method=POST>"
    . "<tr>"
    . "<td><input class=textbox  type=text name=name value='" . $record['name'] . "'> </td>"
    . "<td><input class=textbox size=50 type=url name=url value='" . $record['url'] . "'> </td>"
    . "<td><textarea class=textbox rows=3 cols=50 wrap=physical name=desc>" . $record['description'] . "</textarea></td>"
    . "<input type=hidden name=hidden value=" . $record['name'] . ">"
    . "<td><input type=submit name=update value=update></td>"
    . "<td><input type=submit name=delete value=delete></td>"
    . "</tr>"
    . "</form>";
}
echo""
. "</table>";

mysqli_close($connect);
?>
```

I tried if and else statement if there's something wrong with my code or not. Technically, it says successful, but it doesn't. It's not updating thru mysql and not updating in my input fields. ANY HELP WOULD DO! PLEASE

### **UPDATE**

I got it working. There was an error on my input fields code where the value of my $_POST['hidden'] didn't match the value of the name on my table. Printing the update query using var_dump it helped me look thru my code and got what exactly is the problem.

**Error Code**

```
"<input class=textbox type=text name=name value='" . $record['name'] . "'>"
"<input type=hidden name=hidden value=" . $record['name'] . ">"
```

**Fixed Code**

```
"<input type=hidden name=hidden value='" . $record['name'] . "'>"
```

Comment: First of all, your code is vulnerable to sql-injections (and mysqli supports prepared statements as well as escaping). If this is  actual code from the tutorial, get a new one. Secondly you are not checking for errors on your update statement, which you propably should do if the update is not working.

Comment: escape all $_POST array prior to database update

Comment: @Rangad i did the if and else statement. It always shows Successful but nothing is working

Comment: @DLastCodeBender i tried the mysqli_real_escape_string and mysqli_escape_string. my update is still not working

Comment: output your SQL Query as a string and run it manually on your database and check if its throwing an error.. Also check the parameters passed are the one you wanted..

Comment: @Dinesh can you give me an idea how to do it?

Comment: @Kamilah In Your if (isset($_POST['update']) after the variable $update is assigned with a query.. just echo it out.. using echo $update or var_dump($update) whichever you prefer.. Now run a test on your browser and see what is printed.. once you have that string on your browser and if everything looks fine query your db.. either by using command prompt/terminal or application like Workbench.. and see what happens.. If you are comfortable with posting that string here than do it so we can check if it was created properly.

Comment: @Dinesh my original table http://prntscr.com/5dajrx your suggestion http://prntscr.com/5dak2r what do you think?

Comment: You need to escape the single quote on East's as its breaking the query At a guess

Comment: THANK YOU FOR ALL YOUR HELP!! I GOT IT WORKING. @Dinesh your suggestion made me realize what I did wrong! :D Thank you so much

Comment: @Ben I know they still submit, lol. What I'm saying is why would you base your `WHERE` clause on a static value? Might as well just specify it directly in the query. That's why I want to see the form to determine where the value comes from.

Comment: then this leaves me with 2 conclusions... either your update variables are not sanitized or your WHERE condition  was not met.... make sure $_POST['hidden'] is returning the right word to match the name on your table.... and tell us what was the css command u added that started the problem? hope its not display:none;

Comment: @DLastCodeBender I already got it working :D I missed single quotes which didn't match the same name value on my table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working. There was an error on my input fields code where the value of my $_POST['hidden'] didn't match the value of the name on my table. Printing the update query using var_dump it helped me look thru my code and got what exactly is the problem.

Error Code

```
"<input class=textbox type=text name=name value='" . $record['name'] . "'>"
"<input type=hidden name=hidden value=" . $record['name'] . ">"
```

Fixed Code

```
"<input type=hidden name=hidden value='" . $record['name'] . "'>"
```

Thanks to Dinesh who gave me the idea.

Answer (score 4):

Output your SQL query as a string and run it manually on your database and check if its throwing an error. Also check the parameters passed are the one you wanted.

In your `if (isset($_POST['update'])` after the variable `$update` is assigned with a query, just echo it out using `echo $update` or `var_dump($update)`, whichever you prefer. Now run a test on your browser and see what is printed.

Once you have that string on your browser and if everything looks fine query your database, either by using command prompt/terminal or application like Workbench, and see what happens. If you are comfortable with posting that string here than do it so we can check if it was created properly.

Answer (score 1):

There is one obvious problem with your code:

```
$data = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `maintenance`");
```

When you issue the `SELECT` query, the database server goes to work, collects all the results, and puts them in neat little boxes for you to pick up later.

When `mysqli_query()` returns, all the work has been done, everybody has gone home, and only the night guard is left waiting for you to pick up your results.

```
mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE `maintenance` ...");
```

Another query, another day at the factory. This query doesn't affect the results from yesterday in any way.

```
while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
  ...
}
```

And here, you are picking up yesterdays results.

If you want the updated results to appear on the web page, you need to run the `UPDATE` before the `SELECT`.